# Read JSON Direct from API into DataFrame via PySpark/Databricks

Tags: python, json, azure-databricks

I'm attempting to improve a current process that we have. Presently the process is:

API Call Made > JSON Saved as File > API Calls are iterated ending up with multiple files > Files are then read into a Databricks Dataframe.

I am attempting to remove the need to save the JSON as a file and then using read.json the files themselves into a dataframe before I then iterate through the data.

Is there a way I can read the json response into a string and then read it directly into a data frame?

My attempt is below but it keeps failing:

```
payload={}
headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ==',
      'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='
    }

response = requests.request("GET", apipath, headers=headers, data=payload)

jsonData = json.dumps(response.text)

jsonDataList = []
jsonDataList.append(jsonData)

jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonDataList)

df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
```

However I do a df.printSchema() and get told its "corrupt" data.

I've also tried to do the following:

```
payload={}
headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ==',
      'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='
    }

response = requests.request("GET", apipath, headers=headers, data=payload)

jsonData = json.dumps(response.text)

#jsonDataList = []
#jsonDataList.append(jsonData)

#jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonDataList)

df = spark.read.json(jsonData)
```

But get told relative path in URI and I'm guessing that is because its not reading directly from a file.

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I reproduced  same in my environment. I got below result:***

[image]

**To Resolve above error please follow this code:**

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1,name,href')
db1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([resp.text])

df2 = spark.read.json(db1)

df2.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]